# Recorrer array y reemplazar

Tags: java, array

Tengo este ejercicio, pero no pude avanzar casi.

Retornar un nuevo string con la letra inicial en mayúscula y el resto de letras reemplazar por puntos.

Si el string es "", retornar un string con un punto.

Ejemplo:

```
String1("") → "."
String1("carlos") → "C...."
```

Este es el código que tengo:

```
public String myString1(String str) 
{
 if (str == null || str.isEmpty()) {
    return str;            
  } else {
    return  Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(0)) + str.substring(1, str.length()).toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

Comment: hola @Juan, no has explicado el problema que tienes con tu codigo, solo escribiste lo que parece ser un ejercicio en clases.

Comment: Llevo esto, de ese ejercicio y no se como avanzar mas.

Comment: @Juan, primero mira cómo obtener un `array` con el string que le envías a ese método. Por ahí puedes empezar.

Answer (score 0):

La primera parte que es convertir el primer carácter en mayúscula ya lo tienes realizado, puedes como comentas recorrer un array pero también puedes obtener los siguientes caracteres y reemplazarlos por "." de esta forma:

```
public static String myString1(String str) {
 if(str == null){
  return "";
 }else if (str.isEmpty()) { //String vacio retorna "."
   return ".";            
 } else {
     //Convierte primer caracter en mayuscula.
     String firstLetter = String.valueOf(Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(0)));
     //Convierte siguientes caracteres a "."
     String otherLetters = str.substring(1, str.length()).toLowerCase();     
     nextLetters = otherLetters.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", ".");
     //Retorna resultado
     return firstLetter + nextLetters;
  }
}
```

---

Ejemplos de uso:

**1)**

```
System.out.println("Resultado: " + myString1("carlos"));
```

se tendría como salida:

```
Resultado: C.....
```

**2)**

```
System.out.println("Resultado: " + myString1(""));
```

se tendría como salida:

```
Resultado: .
```

Answer (score 0):

La verdad no vas tan mal, solo te falta reemplazar el resto de caracteres por puntos.
En **Java 8** puede usar [Collections.nCopies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies-int-T-) con [String.join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-) de la forma `String.join("", Collections.nCopies(n, str))` donde `Collections.nCopies(n, str)` crea un objeto **List** con el objeto **str** repetido **n** veces.
y para que cumpla lo que necesitas **str** debe ser el punto y **n** el largo del String -1.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> lista = new LinkedList();
    lista.add("carlos");
    lista.add("c");
    lista.add("");
    lista.add(null);
    for(String data : lista){
        System.out.println(myString1(data));
    }
}
/**
 * si String viene vacio se devuelve un punto  
 * de lo contrario coloca la primera letra en Mayuscula y el resto con puntos
 * @param str
 * @return 
 */
public static String myString1(String str) {
    String dot = ".";
    if (str == null || str.isEmpty()) {
        return dot;            
    } else {
        return  Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(0)) + String.join("", Collections.nCopies(str.length()-1, dot));
    }
}
```

si lo ejecutas saldrá:

```
C.....
C
.
.
```

si por alguna razón usas **Java 11**, es más fácil la parte de la repetición con [repeat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)):

```
str.repeat(n);
```

De estas formas evitas el que se ingrese un carácter extraño e igual sea reemplazado por un punto